# Docker container not running on Linux

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

In our project we use docker to keep our development environments similar. When running it on macOS it works, however on Linux (currently using Manjaro) it states that the container doesn't exist:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml exec web python manage.py migrate --noinput
Error response from daemon: Container 43f405eac00706b22dc075cbcaf33dbbf595971be3ce1955034302cb1284aa5b is not running
make: *** [Makefile:9: build] Error 1
```

This is the makefile for our project:

```
build:
    make down
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml exec web python manage.py migrate --noinput
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml exec web python manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --email name@testmail.org
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml exec web python manage.py startup
```

We tried different systems and different commands, but it always fails when trying to execute the second command.

Comment: Why not have the container's entrypoint do this itself?  Or `docker-compose run` a dedicated container to do the migration?  What's the container's main process, and is it starting successfully?

Comment: We have a lot of scenarios `make build` is only one of them (there is stop, down, prod, pull...) and in each of the cases different commands are used, so we would need to have a lot of entrypoint scripts. So we decided to use the commands via the make file.

Comment: The containers main process should be Django and it isn't starting up correctly.

Comment: If the container doesn't start up correctly, you won't be able to `docker exec` into it.  You need to debug that startup problem first.  Scripting `docker exec` like this isn't usually a best practice; it's better to make your containers operate without manual intervention if you can.

Comment: But when running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build` there is no error message and like I said on macOS it works. So you are saying that the problem is likely in our `docker-compose.yml´?